# How to serve file as Readable Stream?

Tags: node.js, remix.run

I'm trying to create a `Request` object that serves a static file.
The issue is: I need to do `return new Response(<readable stream>)`. However, Node's `fs.createReadStream` returns a `ReadStream` (Node API) instead of a `ReadableStream` (which I believe is a web API).

What is the correct way to generate a `ReadableStream` in Node from a file?

The context:

- I am using remix.run. In remix.run, I need to return a plain `Response` object. A plain `Response` object can either accept a buffer or a `ReadableStream`.
- This is a `Request` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

Comment: It's not clear what your real problem is and what environment you're running in and what the exact situation is that you're trying to solve?  When you say `Request` object, what exactly is that and what are you using it for?  If you're running this in nodejs, why do you need a ReadableStream?  Please explain exactly what you're interfacing with that requires that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone finding this issue - you can use `createReadableStreamFromReadable` to convert `ReadStream` into a `Readable` which can be used to create a `Response`:

```js
import { createReadableStreamFromReadable } from '@remix-run/node';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export async function action() {
  const readableStream = fs.createReadStream('some-file.txt');
  return new Response(createReadableStreamFromReadable(readableStream));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have all the elements to understand the reason for `return new Response(<readable stream>)` so I'm going to assume that you just need to send a file in a Response.

Remix has what we call "[Resource Routes](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes)", which are used for something other than rendering a component (this type of route does not export any), as a more general-purpose endpoint. You'll be able to export a loader that can manage different request methods and returns a new Response with a file and a header.

Take [this example](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes#creating-resource-routes) from the doc linked above which wants to render a component allowing to download a pdf:

```js
// app/routes/reports/$id.js

export async function loader({ params }) {
  return json(await getReport(params.id));
}

export default function Report() {
  const report = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{report.name}</h1>
      <Link to="pdf" reloadDocument>
        View as PDF
      </Link>
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You will notice `<Link to="pdf" reloadDocument>` where "pdf" matches the route below:

```js
// app/routes/reports/$id/pdf.ts

export async function loader({ params }) {
  const report = await getReport(params.id);
  const pdf = await generateReportPDF(report);
  return new Response(pdf, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "app/pdf",
    },
  });
}
```

Hoping that it will be useful to you if I guessed correctly what you needed!